# Adding Image to Dictionary iPhone VS iPad

Tags: objective-c, image, ipad, dictionary

I'm having a very odd problem that I can't understand. I have created an iPhone only app and it works exactly how I want on the iPhone; however, crashes at one point over and over in the iPad. I'm adding a gift image to a dictionary using the following code:

```
 [dictionary setObject:giftImage forKey:key];
```

On the iPhone this works fine; however, on the iPad it causes the following exception:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: A877373A-B588-4631-A850-06C2F23A45F7)
```

I cant understand why the image would be nil when using the iPad, but would be created properly on the iPhone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I have done more testing and on the iPhone giftImage is given a value; however, on the iPad it is null, but I can not figure out why...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *giftImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Comment: Could you describe giftImage?

Comment: @safecase giftImage is the image that is a pointer to a UIImage that is stored in a dictionary. The line [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] defines gift image as a pointer to the image just selected from the UIImagePicker.

Comment: giftImage gets released before you are using it. So retain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the other keys in the `info` dictionary provided to your image picker delegate method and you might see why the image isn't where you expect it to be.